# How can I create an unordered HTML list using JavaScript (without strange behaviour)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-lists

I am trying to capture time from a stopwatch within a browser and display the times (laps) below. To do this, I am intending to create an unordered list from an array within a JavaScript file.

Here is the JS:

```
laps = []:

    function show() {
        $time = document.getElementById('time');
        document.getElementById("capture").setAttribute("disabled","disabled"); // disable capture button until start
        update();
    }

    function update() {
        $time.innerHTML = formatTime(time());
        displayLaps();
    }

    function displayLaps() {
        if (laps == "" || laps.length == 0) {
     return false; // stop the function if the value is empty
      }
    var inner = `Lap ${lap_count} :${formatTime(laps[lap_count-1])}`;
    document.getElementById("laps").innerHTML += '<li>' + inner + '</li>';
    }
```

And the associated html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body onload="show()">
    <div>Time: <span id="time"></span></div>
    <button onclick="onStart()" id="start" style="width:150px">Start</button>
    <button id="capture" style="width:150px">Capture</button>

    <div id="laps"><ul></ul></div>

<script src=".\stopwatch.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting peculiar behaviour though. It seems that the `+=` operator on the last line of code keeps adding rows that display the last array vaue (see below), whereas replacing this with a simple `=` operator just creates a single row that is then replaced every time a new lap value is added to the array.

[image: Apparently infinite rows of the last array value]

I'm obviously missing something, but would appreciate some guidance, if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to show more code; there's nothing obvious wrong with it but it depends on how often / when the function is called. (edit: missed lis getting appened to div instead of ul)

Comment: The only thing I can spot is that you are updating the inner html of the div but inside that you have a ul. So you should be appending to the UL not the div. You can use the append() method instead of using += on the inner Html

Comment: but yes please share the rest of your code

Comment: ... [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) ... [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) ... [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: At risk of pasting too much code here, I've added the other methods that I think are relevant:

Comment: Ah, I found the problem - you were right, I was inadvertently creating a loop by calling displayLaps() in the wrong place. Thank you so much for your time and kind suggestions!!